# Write errors to the log unless the user is an administrator

Tags: 7

Under error reporting it is possible (and actually recommended for live sites) to write errors to the log, but not to the screen as well. I don't want to show errors to my users, but at the same time I never check my logs. Is there a way of only showing these errors on screen to administrator users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set error messages to none and install this [Logging and alerts](http://drupal.org/project/logging_alerts) module.

> Currently, the following modules are included:
>
> Email logging and alerts Allows routing of watchdog messages to
>   various email addresses, based on their severity levels. For example,
>   emergency and critical messages need to go to a pager or mobile phone
>   email address, while debug messages go no where.
>
> Web server logging Allows routing of watchdog messages to the web
>   server's error log. Note that what is in your PHP configuration for
>   error_log defines where the message will go. For example, on a UNIX
>   like system, this will be syslog(3), which may end up in
>   /var/log/apache2/error.log, and on Windows, it would be the event log.
>
> You define which severity levels are to go to the error log. For
>   example, you can only specify that emergency and critical messages
>   need to go to the error log, and use other modules for the other
>   levels.
>
> Watchdog triggers Provides a trigger for watchdog events. You may now
>   trigger actions when an event occurs.
>
> Watchdog rules Provides rules integration for watchdog events. You may
>   now trigger additional ruleset responses when an event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Using the devel module you can print to the screen errors that you are seeing, but that requires custom work to catch specific exceptions that you expecting to see.